# Array of images into storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am making little game in angular and i have problem how to export array with images to storage so when i reload the page it doesn't disappear. Array is made of random items from other array and adding next item is by pressing button.

That's my code in typescript

```js
containers = [];
images = [
  { id: 0, name: "sword", url: "../../../../assets/img/sword.png" },
  { id: 1, name: "sword2", url: "../../../../assets/img/sword2.png" },
];

add() {
  let index = Math.round(Math.random());
  this.containers.push(this.images[index]);
}
```

and this is in html:

```html
<button (click)="add()">Add</button>
<div id="content">
  <div id="contentInside" *ngFor="let image of containers">
    <img class="item" src="{{image.url}}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[I want to keep it looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqcnZ.png)

Comment: By storage you mean localStorage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a copy of your image array in localstorage as

```
localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(this.images))
```

And retrive those images on browser reload by simply doing

```
private images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
```